# How can my Bot Framework bot send a message to a Skype ID that has never messaged the bot?

Tags: botframework

I am developing a bot for Skype with the Microsoft Bot Framework. I need to send messages to users which have never sent messages to my bot. I know their Skype ID, they gave me that through a form on my site. Is this possible?

Comment: For security and anti-spam reasons, this is not a feature of bot framework.

Answer (score 3):

Initiating communication from the bot to a user is not a feature of the Bot Framework.  For the Skype channel specifically, a user must first add the bot as a contact.  Then, the bot is able to send Proactive Messages to the user.  More information on proactive messages can be found here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/bot-framework/dotnet/bot-builder-dotnet-proactive-messages

This repository has some proactive messaging examples: https://github.com/Microsoft/BotBuilder-Samples/tree/master/CSharp/core-proactiveMessages